# How do I read from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, cmd

I'm trying to get my program to read code from a .txt and then read it back to me, but for some reason, it crashes the program when I compile. Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! :)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        string    winDir=System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
        StreamReader reader=new  StreamReader(winDir + "\\Name.txt");
            try {      
            do {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }   
            while(reader.Peek() != -1);
            }      
            catch 
            { 
            Console.WriteLine("File is empty");
            }
            finally
            {
            reader.Close();
            }

    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't crash on compile

Comment: I think you don't have access to `windir\name.txt` run program as elevated and check

Comment: Post the error message what you're getting to get help

Comment: Please consider searching for your question title first - i.e. MSDN have good basic [How-to on reading file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) .

Comment: When executing the .exe, I get a "Program.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close" Window.

Comment: I agree with other posters, there is insufficient information about your situation to give better help. Run it in debug mode and examine the exception there. Post the exception details here. I'm personally leaning towards a filesystem permissions issue. (Could be reader.Close() is not a valid operation at that point as well.)

Comment: Wrap whole main in try/catch and tell us what is the exception you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like your solution for two simple reasons:

1)I don't like gotta Cath 'em all(try catch). For avoing check if the file exist using `System.IO.File.Exist("YourPath")`

2)Using this code you haven't dispose the streamreader. For avoing this is better use the using constructor like this: `using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(path)){ //Your code}`

Usage example:

```
        string path="filePath";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The file not exist!");
```

Answer (score 3):

If your file is located in the same folder as the `.exe`, all you need to do is `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("File.txt");`

Otherwise, where File.txt is, put the full path to the file. Personally, I think it's easier if they are in the same location.

From there, it's as simple as `Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());`

If you want to read all lines and display all at once, you could do a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineAmount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(winDir + "\Name.txt")

If all you're trying to do is display this as output in the console, you could do that pretty compactly:

```
private static string winDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(winDir, "Name.txt")));
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Also, why not `Path.Combine(winDir, "Name.txt")` -- it's even better.

Comment: Im pretty new to C#, so I'm not sure what the best ways for file IO are yet. Could you explain how I would use this to extract a list of values into my program? Thanks :)

Comment: The method above leverages a streamreader in a Using block, so it basically does what you were trying to do without having to write it all out.  It returns a string array representing the lines of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below if you want the result as a string instead of an array.

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(winDir, "Name.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(winDir + "\\Name.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using(var reader = new  StreamReader(fs))
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework has a variety of ways to read a text file.  Each have pros and cons... lets go through two.

The first, is one that many of the other answers are recommending:

```
String allTxt = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(winDir, "Name.txt"));
```

This will read the entire file into a single `String`. It will be quick and painless. It comes with a risk though... If the file is large enough, you may run out of memory.  Even if you can store the entire thing into memory, it may be large enough that you will have paging, and will make your software run quite slowly.  The next option addresses this.

The second solution allows you to work with one line at a time and not load the entire file into memory:

```
foreach(String line in File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(winDir, "Name.txt")))
  // Do Work with the single line.
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

This solution may take a little longer for files because it's going to do work MORE OFTEN with the contents of the file... however, it will prevent awkward memory errors.

I tend to go with the second solution, but only because I'm paranoid about loading huge `Strings` into memory.